# Hibernate generate unnecessary cross join and duplicate results

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to write a dynamic query with spring data jpa and criteria api, but hibernate generate unnecessary cross join and duplicate results.

Entity class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private String id;
private String accountId;
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime createdTs;
@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime updatedTs;
```

Query:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<FavouriteItemEntity> root = query.from(MyEntity.class);

    Path<String> accountIdPath = root.get("accountId");
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    predicates.add(cb.equal(accountIdPath, accountId));
    query.select(cb.count(query.from(MyEntity.class)));
    query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    return entityManager.createQuery(query)
            .getSingleResult();
```

Hql generate cross join and duplicate results

```
Hibernate: select count(favouritei1_.id) as col_0_0_ from favourite favouritei0_ cross join favourite favouritei1_ where favouritei0_.account_id=?
```

instead of

```
Hibernate: select count(f.id) from favourite f where f.account_id = ?
```

why is this happening?

Comment: please enter sample data and desired out put

Comment: table contains 3 records, result (count) output: 9 (each entry is selected 3 times)

Comment: Why do you use cross join? Can't answer with a simple select?

Comment: I use just select count, but hibernate generate cross join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake when working with Criteria queries. You call `query.from` twice, thus a cross join. Call it once instead:

```
query.select(cb.count(root));
```